# PHP Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'MyApp\Chat' not found in C:\1\bin\chat-server.php:9

Tags: php, websocket

estoy instalando ratchet pero a la hora de ejecutar el server al cmd no me encuentra la ruta del MyApp\Chat

el codigo del composer json es:

```
{
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "MyApp\\": "src"
    }
},
"require": {
    "cboden/ratchet": "^0.4"
}
```

}

y el del sel server:

```
<?php

use Ratchet\Server\IoServer;
use MyApp\Chat;

    require dirname(__DIR__) . '/vendor/autoload.php';

    $server = IoServer::factory(
        new Chat(),
        8080
    );

    $server->run();

?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

De acuerdo a tu escenario deberías tener ejecutados los siguientes pasos:

Orden de carpetas:

```
app
---src
```

Creas en la raíz, es decir en la carpeta `app`un archivo llamado: **composer.json** con la siguiente estructura:

```
{
    "name": "user/app",
    "require": {
        "cboden/ratchet": "^0.4"
    },
    "autoload":{
        "psr-4": {
            "MyApp\\": "src"
        }
    }
}
```

Ahora ejecutas el comando:

```
composer install
```

Posterior dentro de la carpeta `src` que esta dentro de `app`, creas un archivo llamado: `Chat.php` y otro llamado: `server.php`

**Archivo `Chat.php`**

Aquí deberás copiar el código del archivo `Chat.php` que esta [en el siguiente enlace](http://socketo.me/docs/hello-world)

Tu archivo `server.php` déjalo con el mismo código que ya esta

Finalmente ejecuta el comando:

```
composer dump-autoload -o
```

El anterior comando generará la lista completa de clases requeridas en el archivo: `autoload_classmap.php` en la ruta: `app/vendor/composer/`

Finalmente desde la consola deberías ejecutar: `php app.php` a nivel de la carpeta `src` y tener el resultado esperado.

Comment: primero que todo te agradezco demasiado tu ayuda, he realizado todos los pasos y me ha funcionado ahora el problema es cuando quiero conectar al cliente (ya sea firefox o chrome) un error que dice "Firefox no puede establecer una conexión con el servidor en ws://localhost:8080/." pero del lado del servidor me sale conectado y pues eso me hace suponer que no envia el handshake de lado del servidor, tienes idea de que estará mal?

Comment: al momento no @JonathanSolares ahorita solo te puedo apoyar con esta respuesta, de todos modos si consideras que la duda da para otra pregunta eres libre de publicarla y seguro alguien mas de la comunidad te podrá auxiliar :D